# No sound on chat notifications skype

Tags: windows-10, skype

Can you tell me why my skype doesn't give any sound on chat notifications? I have win 10 pro desktop. All sounds are working fine on call and etc. The problem here is no sound on chat notification when Skype is on the taskbar. But it shows message coming notification on the taskbar icon. But no sound. Any clue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Same problem here. One thing I noticed is that sometimes it does make a sound, but it's just too short, barely noticeable, as if it stops playing abruptly.

Comment: similar issue with me. I don't get both notification and sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have this issue now. I didn't do anything myself for this. No idea something happened accidentally. But I strongly believe Windows latest updates fixed this issue. Now I can see and have sound through notification section when I have a skype message.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the problem is related to specific user or a group like in my case !

1. Right click on a group/contact,
2. Click on "Manage group"
3. Scroll to the bottom
4. "Notifications" should be **checked**
5. "Smart notifications" should be **uncheched**

[image]